# Hibernate ManyToMany save

Tags: java, hibernate, spring-data-jpa

I have two classes with relation ManyToMany, I want create Audiences and later add them to events, but it throwing "detached" exception.

```
class Event {
    @ManyToMany(
            fetch = FetchType.LAZY,
            targetEntity = Audience.class,
            cascade = {CascadeType.PERSIST, CascadeType.MERGE})
    @JoinTable(name = "UC_EVENT_AUDIENCE",
            joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "event_id"),
            inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "audience_id"))    
    private List<Audience> targetAudiences = new ArrayList<>();
}

clsas Audience {
    @ManyToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, mappedBy = "targetAudiences")
    private List<Event> events = new ArrayList<>();
}

public void run(ApplicationArguments args) throws Exception {
    //Generate audience data
    List<Audience> audiences = dataGenerator.createAudiences();
    //Save to db
    audienceRepository.save(audiences);

    Event event = new Event();
    event.setTargetAudiences(audiences);    
    eventRepository.save(events);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are doing the audience save first but in relationship defined in your code:

***Event will handle the persisting of the audience due to this:***

```
 @ManyToMany(
            fetch = FetchType.LAZY,
            targetEntity = Audience.class,
            cascade = {CascadeType.PERSIST, CascadeType.MERGE})
```

So you first create the audiences, then create event, then attach audience list to event and save the event object in the end to database.

Comment: You mean if i will comment "audienceRepository.save(audiences)" and then save "Event" it will save my Audience? I Ignored "audienceRepository.save(audiences)" and It's looks like Event not saving it, because when I "findAll" Audiences there is nothing.

Comment: are you finding audience through the event object or directly finding audience ?

Comment: you also have to set the event for the audience before saving the event. since its a bi-directional relationship

Comment: Thank you, I will do this. All this hibernate binding confusing.

Comment: Yes bindings are confusing but, try do try use cases to get better understanding. https://howtoprogramwithjava.com/hibernate-manytomany-unidirectional-bidirectional/ try this link it may help in understanding bidirectional realtionships.

Answer (score 0):

As a variant you can use like this 'PrePersist' util method to 'link' events and audiences:

```
@Entity
public class Event {

    @ManyToMany(cascade = {CascadeType.PERSIST, CascadeType.MERGE})
    private final Set<Audience> audiences = new HashSet<>();

    @PrePersist
    public void addAudiences() {
        audiences.forEach(audience -> audience.getEvents().add(this));
    }
}

@Entity
public class Audience {

    @ManyToMany(mappedBy = "audiences")
    private final Set<Event> events = new HashSet<>();

    //...
    public Set<Event> getEvents() {
        return events;
    }
}
```

More info about ManyToMany association and 'utilities  methods': [Hibernate User Guide](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/5.2/userguide/html_single/Hibernate_User_Guide.html#associations-many-to-many)

My [example](https://github.com/Cepr0/restdemo/tree/master/src/main/java/restsdemo/example9) and [tests](https://github.com/Cepr0/restdemo/tree/master/src/test/java/restsdemo/example9).

Answer (score 0):

I done this and it's work for me:

```
public class Event {

    @ManyToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    @JoinTable(name = "event_audience",
            joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "event_id"),
            inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "audience_id"),
            uniqueConstraints = @UniqueConstraint(columnNames = {"event_id", "audience_id"}))
    private List<Audience> audiences = new ArrayList<>();
}

public class Audience {

    @Column(name = "audience_name", nullable = false, unique = true)
    private String name;
}
```

Also i have two repositories for save Audience and Events extending spring's JpaRepository.

Now i can create Audience like this:

```
audienceRepository.save(new Audience("Name"));
```

And add them to my Events like this:

```
Event eventFirst = new Event();
eventFirst.getAudiences().add(audiences.get(0));
eventRepository.save(eventFirst);
```